# Not operator in MATCH

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I wanna find nodes that are not in a relation. So I was using while i was finding the nodes in a relation with current node instance like;

```
@Query(value = "start user=node({self}) match (user)<-[r:KNOWS]-(known) return known")
@Fetch
private Iterable<GraphUser> knowsMe;
```

But when I tried to find nodes that does not knows current node, I found a solution and it is like;

```
    @Query(value = "start user=node({self}), doesNotKnowMe=node(*) where has(user.userId) and NOT((user)<-[:KNOWS]-(doesNotKnowMe))  return doesNotKnowMe")
    @Fetch
    private Iterable<GraphUser> doesNotKnowMe;
```

When I run this neo4j online executor, it works well.(http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher) 
The sample that I used on the site is like;

```
START m=node:node_auto_index(id="603"), actor=node(*) 
WHERE HAS (actor.name) AND NOT ((m)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor)) 
RETURN actor
```

Note: To get a result, you should put a node that does not in a relation with movies. If it exits, the query will result your added record.

When I want to run this with spring-data-neo4j, there is a problem. It does not like relation([:KNOWS]) not having an alias like [r:KNOWS].

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' property not found for NodeImpl#0.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.newPropertyNotFoundException(Primitive.java:184)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getProperty(Primitive.java:179)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getProperty(NodeImpl.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom
```

But as you may know, We can't define allias in `WHERE` clause. We can define it in `MATCH` clause but we cant use `NOT` operator in match too.

How can I use `NOT` operator in match as it can be used in `WHERE`. Or is there a way to fix `spring-data-neo4j` exception somehow.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Micheal Bachman mentioned, I had been missing checking the object has userId. The missing part is `has(doesNotKnowMe.userId)`. Hence I guarantied that the node will be my model even if there is another type node.

```
    @Query(value = "start user=node({self}), doesNotKnowMe=node(*) where has(user.userId) and has(doesNotKnowMe.userId) and NOT((user)<-[:KNOWS]-(doesNotKnowMe))  return doesNotKnowMe")
    @Fetch
    private Iterable<GraphUser> doesNotKnowMe;
```

So, I could get nodes that is not a relation with the query above.

Thank to Michal Bachman.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if the exception says a different thing that you're claiming to be the problem. It complains that the root node (node with ID = 0) does not have the __type__ property, which I believe is where Spring data stores its internal info to be able to create objects out of your nodes.

Check what your root node represents. Delete it if you don't think it should be there and try again. Alternatively, if it represents something like a user in your system, have a look at another user node, take whatever value it has for the __type__ property, and set the same thing onto the root node.